# Android RecyclerView : Abstract method not implemented

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Application crashed when swipe to delete an item from Recyclerview. Error log is as below.It was working before now updated to  com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0 and recyclerview-animators-1.2.2.jar. Now it is crashing, Please help me. Thanks in advance.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.timecard, PID: 2876
>       java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.animateChange(RecyclerView.java)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.animateChange(RecyclerView.java:3062)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2924)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>               at

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My team faced a similar problem just yesterday. The solution is to update the `recyclerview-animators` used in your project to its newest version, `2.0.1`:

> compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.0.1'

Appearantly it's a known issue as the developer has also [mentioned](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators#gradle) about older versions's incompatibility with Support Library 23.0.1.

Comment: Will please explain detail how to implement .jar file in android studio and use it. i also implement but it was like compile files('libs/recyclerview-animators-1.2.2.jar')  . I hop you understand what i have problem. Please replay and help

Answer (score 3):

To use https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators with RecyclerView follow the [Setup](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators#setup) and update the library

Gradle

If you are using a RecyclerView `23.1.0` (released Oct 2015) or higher.

```
dependencies {
  // jCenter
  compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.1.0'
}
```

If you are using a RecyclerView `23.0.1` or below.

```
dependencies {
  // jCenter
  compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Will please explain detail how to implement .jar file in android studio and use it. i also implement but it was like compile files('libs/recyclerview-animators-1.2.2.jar')  . I hop you understand what i have problem. Please replay and help